# How to avoid repetition in PHP while loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am trying to edit check box values using more than one while loop but I'm getting repeated values. How to block this repetition? Here is the code:

```
<tr>
<?php 
$qqqq = mysql_query("select * from tbl_color ");
while($rr = mysql_fetch_array($qqqq)) {
    $dara = $rr['color'];
    $ids = $rr['id'];
    $datas = mysql_query("select * from ifix_model_tbl where id='".$g_select_id."'");
    while($rw = mysql_fetch_array($datas)) {
        $fg = $rw['color']; 
        $ecolor = unserialize($fg);
        foreach($ecolor as $ucolor) { 
            echo $ucolor = $ucolor['id'];
            ?>            
            <td width="130"> 
                <input style="padding-top:100px" name="colo[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $ids?>"
                    <?php if($ucolor == $ids){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>
                / >
                <?php echo $dara;?>
            </td>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
</tr>
```

Now I am getting result like this:

[image]

I need the result like this:

[image]

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: No, but I'm sure you are perfectly capable of doing it if you've gotten this far. PDO Is actually easier to use than `mysql_query`. Follow those links there. That tutorial takes like twenty minutes to read and not much longer to put into practice.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html) operator in MySQL:

```
$qqqq = mysql_query(" SELECT DISTINCT id, color FROM tbl_color ");
```

**Note:**

1) don't use mysql_* THEY ARE DEPRECATED. Use [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

2) try using column names in `SELECT` statement rather than using `SELECT *`. It will help to improve performance of your query.

Comment: @user5533614, please check updated query and try accordingly.

Comment: try using same in second query as well

Comment: changed second query but still have same issue